# How to display temperature in celsius as RGB in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i create background color base on celsius temperature? suppose i have a set of temperature values:
[19°,29°,30°,32°], and i want to represent them as RGB colors, how can it be done?

I was thinking to set some default colors, and present them by the temperature,something like this:

```
const red = 'red';
const cyan = 'cyan';

if((temp < hottest ){ return red;}
if((temp > hottest ){ return cyan;}
```

But i don't like that method beacause i want to get the color tones rather them a flat color....

I've found [This](https://gist.github.com/paulkaplan/5184275) solution but i can't get it to work with Celsius...

Comment: " want to get the color tones rather them a flat color" What exactly do you mean by that? Can you maybe scetch up how you want it to look?

Comment: @LucaKiebel thanks - i meant to show thier true represetation - rather then a flat color - so if the tempature is 30 degress - then to show a tone color of red, which is different then 27 degress - which is also hot - and should be a more orange color then red.....

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with "celcius" and is purely about "I have an ordered list of numbers, I'd like to map them to a color gradient", for which there are already answers on SO.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it's not accurate... i was looking for a package or a librery that does what i was looking for... if the is a better and simpler solution then i'll be happy.. but since i didn't found anything like it - then it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Remember that you're not posting to SO to ask for a library or package (because that's literally an example of one of the reasons your question will [get closed](/help/on-topic)), you're asking how to do a specific thing. In this case, mapping a set of numbers to a color gradient. That's something that's been asked before, so as part of the [searching and researching](/help/how-to-ask) that you're expected to do before posting, you would have found those. If you did, please explain how what you found _didn't_ address what you needed, because without that information, this is just a duplicate.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans please explain where is the solution for dealing with weahter tempature... you are under the false assumption that i'm just looking for a way to "Map numbers"..but as i explained - it's not  - after i've did some deep looking i've found this solution https://gist.github.com/paulkaplan/5184275 , which is similar to what i'm looking for - so check it out and then decide if it's is a duplicate.

Comment: there is no such thing as "temperature": you're showing a list of increasing sequential numbers. Whether those are distances, or temperature, or financial figures, or the height of corn over a season, is entirely irrelevant for the act of "mapping this numbers to specific (gradients of) colors". If you colours between red and cyan, then the same logic that you use for _any_ number-to-color mapping still applies. Normally you use HSL for this, because it gives a stable color range, but if you _really_ need RGB then there are also other answers that on SO that explain how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume that 0° should be blue(rgb(0, 0, 255)) and 100° is red(rgb(255, 0, 0)).

```
const maxTemp = 100;
const minTemp = 0;
const redVal = 255 / (maxTemp - minTemp) * (temp - minTemp);
const blueVal = 255 / (maxTemp - minTemp) * (maxTemp - temp);
...
  <div style={{ backgroundColor : `rgb(${redVal}, 0, ${blueVal})` }}
```

Comment: thanks - something isn't add up.... if my tempature is 30 deg. then what i'm getting is rgb(76, 0, 178) - which is blue....

Comment: You need to change maxTemp. if you set that as 30deg then you will get red as you want.

Comment: Just change maxTemp like `const maxTemp = 35`